# jasmine asynchronous testing waitsFor/runs timeout

Tags: unit-testing, testing, coffeescript, jasmine, phantomjs

I have a function which loads some HTML into the page and then attaches the DOM elements and event listeners and sets a variable `loaded`to true (for testing purposes). It's all wrapped in a parent function so I can pass in arguments and control the namespace, with functions I need to test exposed in the return object.

```
((win) ->
    win.PanelLoader = (args) ->

        loaded = false

        el =
            container: $(".container")

        showPanel = ->
            $.get "panel.html", (data) ->
                el.container.append(data)
                attachDOMElements()
                loaded = true

        attachDOMElements = ->
            el.panel =  $(".panel")

        panelHasBeenLoaded = ->
            loaded

        showPanel()

        return {} =
            el:     el
            showPanel:  showPanel
) this
```

panelHasBeenLoaded() simply returns false until the AJAX request is successful. Then in my spec file I have:

```
it "should confirm when the panel is loaded", ->
    panelLoader = PanelLoader()
    expect(panelLoader.el.panel).toBe(undefined)
    waitsFor (->
        panelLoader.panelHasBeenLoaded()
    ), "It took too long to load in the panel", 3000
    runs ->
        expect(panelLoader.el.panel.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
```

I'm assuming that it's initialising the PanelLoader, confirming that there is no 'panel' DOM element, then the `waitsFor` should block until `panelHasBeenLoaded() returns true, timing out after 3 seconds (should be plenty of time, running off localhost), then it runs the test, expecting the DOM element to now be there.

The problem I'm having is that it's always timing out, causing the 2nd expect test to fail. It's all working when I test in the browser so why isn't my unit test working?

I'm using jasmine and phantom JS for testing, via the grunt-contrib-jasmine runner.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that Jasmine's `waitsFor()` only applies on `runs()` blocks.
for example,

```
runs(function() {
        asyncMethod();
        console.log('an asynchronous method');
    }, 'an asynchronous method');

    waitsFor(function() {
        return x == 1;
    }, 'x to be equal to 1', 6000);

    console.log('this executes between two runs()');

    runs(function() {
        console.log('another sequential block');
    }, 'another sequential block');
```

means that the 2nd `runs()` is not executed until the `waitsFor()`, but the `console.log()`, which is not nested in a `runs()`, is executed without waiting.
I don't see a `runs()` before `waitsFor()` in your code, which is why the `waitsFor()` probably does nothing.